# How to connect to root with Oracle Developer VM

Tags: oracle, oracle-12c, containers

I have the [Oracle Database App Development VM](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/community/developer-vm/index.html) (12c) and am trying to create a new container. Specifically:

```
conn / as sysdba
create pluggable database pdborcl admin user system identified by oracle FILE_NAME_CONVERT=('/u01/app/oracle/oradata/cdb1/pdbseed/', '/u01/app/oracle/oradata/cdb1/pdb2'');
```

However, I cannot connect to the root container. The above `conn` spits out:

```
  URL           = jdbc:oracle:oci8:@(DESCRIPTION =    (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = 0.0.0.0)(PORT = 1521))    (CONNECT_DATA =      (SERVER = DEDICATED)      (SERVICE_NAME = orcl)    )  )
  Error Message = ORA-01017: invalid username/password; logon denied
  USER          = 
  URL           = jdbc:oracle:thin:@(DESCRIPTION =    (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = 0.0.0.0)(PORT = 1521))    (CONNECT_DATA =      (SERVER = DEDICATED)      (SERVICE_NAME = orcl)    )  )
  Error Message = ORA-01017: invalid username/password; logon denied

Warning: You are no longer connected to ORACLE.
```

And `sqlplus / as sysdba` returns:

```
ERROR:
ORA-01017: invalid username/password; logon denied
```

Logging in with `sqlplus system as sysdba` logs into the connection `ORCL`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason for `sqlplus / as sysdba` not working is:

```
[oracle@localhost ~]$ grep -i two_task .bashrc
if test "m$DONOTSETTWO_TASK" = "m"
        export TWO_TASK=ORCL
[oracle@localhost ~]$ grep -i two_task .bashrc -A 1
if test "m$DONOTSETTWO_TASK" = "m"
        then
        export TWO_TASK=ORCL
        fi
[oracle@localhost ~]$ echo $TWO_TASK 
ORCL
```

SQL*Plus connections automatically connect to the TNS alias defined in the `TWO_TASK` environment variable. When it is set, `sqlplus / as sysdba` does not work.

It is like trying this (will not work):

```
sqlplus /@ORCL as sysdba
```

To "fix" this:

```
[oracle@localhost ~]$ unset TWO_TASK
[oracle@localhost ~]$ sqlplus / as sysdba

SQL*Plus: Release 12.2.0.1.0 Production on Fri May 11 15:20:59 2018

Copyright (c) 1982, 2016, Oracle.  All rights reserved.


Connected to:
Oracle Database 12c Enterprise Edition Release 12.2.0.1.0 - 64bit Production

SQL>
```

You can not connect to a PDB directly with SQL*Plus, you need to use a TNS alias or EZCONNECT. Setting `TWO_TASK` takes care of this, so you can login with for example `sqlplus hr/hr` directly to the PDB, without manually specifying its address.

I guess Oracle just wanted to make simple to connect to the `ORCL` PDB - instead of actually explaining how things work.

Comment: Oh man, that's crazy. Thank you! I found a similar answer elsewhere but was looking in `.bash_profile` where the variable obviously wasn't being set.

Comment: Do you know why `conn / as sysdba` from within the sqlcl doesn't work?

Comment: @Druckles Same reason. If you start sqlcl with the icon on the desktop, that starts a new terminal with `TWO_TASK` set. If you use `unset TWO_TASK` and `sql / as sysdba` in a terminal, you can log in.

Comment: Yeah, I assumed that, but how can I set it up to connect to a different container or even ask? I tried commenting out the set in the `.bashrc`, even changing it to something else (PDBORCL) to no effect. This isn't so important, just more out of interest. And `sqlplus` called from the command line has terrible input support. Cursor keys are not captured correctly for instance.

Comment: @Druckles Comment the lines related to `TWO_TASK` in `.bashrc`. Log out from the desktop session, log in again, and you are good to go.

Comment: We totally explain how this works in the Docs, here https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/NETAG/concepts.htm#NETAG002 And yes, we wanted it to be easy to connect to the PDB.

Answer (score 1):

ALL of the passwords are 'oracle'

That includes:
 OS: root
 OS: oracle
 Database: SYS
 Database: SYSTEM
 Database: HR

```
oracle@vbgeneric ~]$ sqlplus sys as sysdba

SQL*Plus: Release 12.2.0.1.0 Production on Fri May 11 11:43:25 2018

Copyright (c) 1982, 2016, Oracle.  All rights reserved.

Enter password: 

Connected to:
Oracle Database 12c Enterprise Edition Release 12.2.0.1.0 - 64bit Production

SQL>
```

However, you're running into something different.

And it's discussed [here](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/database/multitenant-part1-pdbs-2193987.html).

> Using TWO_TASK. A third way is by defining the TWO_TASK operating
>   system variable to point to the PDB you want to connect to:

```
[oracle@prosrv1 schema]$ export TWO_TASK=PDB1
```

And, then you can connect as usual without giving a connect string:

```
[oracle@prosrv1 schema]$ sqlplus system/oracle
```

I prefer this last approach because it simulates a database connection prior to introduction of the PDB. If you connect to a specific PDB the majority of the time, all you have to do is to set this variable in the shell initialization file (e.g. .profile in case of bourne shell) of the user so that the variable is automatically set when you log in. If you need to know which PDB you are connected right now in SQL*Plus, just use the following command: To show which container (or, the PDB) you are connected to:

```
SQL> show con_id
CON_ID
------------------------------
5

SQL> show con_name
CON_NAME
------------------------------
PDB1
```

Comment: Sorry, this doesn't answer the question; I know what the passwords are.

Comment: I didn't see the 2md line where you created the pdb, I'll delete my answer with my apologies

Comment: Can't delete so I'll fix the answer