# I have an error before I connect to the user Oracle 12c

Tags: oracle, linux

After that, I log in normally.

I tried it sqlplus as sysdba error is the same

Why this error occurs

I'm a beginner

```
[oracle@localhost ~]$ sqlplus "/as sysdba"

SQL*Plus: Release 12.2.0.1.0 Production on Wed Nov 21 13:08:51 2018

Copyright (c) 1982, 2016, Oracle.  All rights reserved.

ERROR:
ORA-01017: invalid username/password; logon denied


Enter user-name: system
Enter password: 
Last Successful login time: Wed Nov 21 2018 13:07:42 -05:00

Connected to:
Oracle Database 12c Enterprise Edition Release 12.2.0.1.0 - 64bit Production
```

Comment: @mustaccio This is valid syntax, we can do `sqlplus / as sysdba`  without quotes starting with 10g. Until 9i, the quotes were required. `"/as sysdba"` and `"/ as sysdba"` both works.

Comment: But why do I get an error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Possible reasons:

- You have `SQLNET.AUTHENTICATION_SERVICES=(NONE)` set in `sqlnet.ora` which disables operating system authentication based on group membership (`$ORACLE_HOME/network/admin/sqlnet.ora`, or `$TNS_ADMIN/sqlnet.ora`, it `$TNS_ADMIN` is set).
- your user (`oracle`) is not the member of the group configured to be used for operating system authentication. Groups can be found in `$ORACLE_HOME/rdbms/lib/config.c`.
- You have the environmental variable `TWO_TASK` set to something which is automatically added to `sqlplus` connection attemts as a TNS alias. For example if `TWO_TASK` is set to `ORCL`, `sqlplus / as sysdba` will become `sqlplus /@ORCL as sysdba` in the background, where operating system authentication does not work.

Comment: I use pre-built Oracle 12c
So I think the settings are good

Comment: @petar Never trust anything pre-built, especially from Oracle. We encountered this already with their VM, same issue here, with `TWO_TASK` set: https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/206500/how-to-connect-to-root-with-oracle-developer-vm/206521

Comment: Thank you very much, I solved my problem with `unset TWO_TASK`

Comment: I read about TWO_TASK, but I'm not quite clear about it,
I would like to ask you to send me a useful link for understanding TWO_TASK

Comment: @petar https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/NETAG/concepts.htm#NETAG363

Comment: Thanks, after `unset TWO_TASK` my user has been deleted

Comment: I don't mind that, I did not have important data on the user,
Is it normal or is there another problem?

Comment: @petar Your user is not deleted. You logged in to the root container of the CDB, instead of the pluggable database. https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/12.2/cncpt/introduction-to-the-multitenant-architecture.html#GUID-267F7D12-D33F-4AC9-AA45-E9CD671B6F22